# Why does GetObject return an BITMAP with null bmBits?

Tags: c++, windows, gdi

Context: I'm trying to take a screenshot of another window to feed it into OpenCV. I found some code on the web that should be able to convert a BITMAP to something OpenCV can work with. Unfortunately I ran into some trouble.

Question: Why is the bmBits attribute/member always null? (I also tried with PrintWindow instead of BitBlt the result was the same)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::wstring windowName = L"Calculator";

    RECT rect;
    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, windowName.c_str());
    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);

    HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
    HBITMAP hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, 
        rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top);
    SelectObject(hdc, hbmp);

    PrintWindow(hwnd, hdc, PW_CLIENTONLY);

    BITMAP bmp;
    GetObject(hbmp, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a screenshot with this code, just off-hand ? Looks like it. PrintWindow isn't what you need if that is the case. All it does is send a WM_PRINT to the target window with a DC on which to dump. There is no guarantee that window will even process that message, and if so, do what you want. You almost have everything you need, but I believe you need to be using a BitBlt() to pull bits from the screen DC to your compatible DC with your fresh bitmap ready to receive them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `bmBits` member is non-null for DIB sections. For device-dependent bitmaps (such as the one you're creating), the `bmBits` is not set because the pixels are on the video card, not in main memory.

In your example, you need to change `CreateCompatibleBitmap` to `CreateDIBSection` if you want direct access to the bits.

Answer (score 12):

Just for information.
When loading bitmap from file and want to use BITMAP **.bmBits** (for **glTexImage2D**, **glDrawPixels**):

```
LoadImage(NULL, "path_to.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0,
                                       LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

u must specify flag `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION`

```
HBITMAP hBmp = NULL;
BITMAP BMp;
hBmp = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(NULL, "bitmap.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0,
                                       LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
GetObject(hBmp, sizeof(BMp), &BMp);
//BMp.bmBits now points to data
```

Answer (score 5):

From **[GetObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144904(v=vs.85).aspx)** documentation on MSDN. Please note the second paragraph.

> If *hgdiobj* is a handle to a bitmap created by calling **CreateDIBSection**, and the specified buffer is large enough, the **GetObject** function returns a `DIBSECTION` structure. In addition, the *bmBits* member of the `BITMAP` structure contained within the `DIBSECTION` will contain a pointer to the bitmap's bit values.
>
> If *hgdiobj* is a handle to a bitmap created by any other means, **GetObject** returns only the width, height, and color format information of the bitmap. You can obtain the bitmap's bit values by calling the **GetDIBits** or **GetBitmapBits** function.

Answer (score -2):

One thing which you could do is to look at the return value of GetObject. If 0 you know something has gone wrong. Something wrong with the parameters of the call.