# Creating, displaying, and then accessing bitmap/DIB data (w/o GetBitmapBits())

Tags: c++, bitmap, mfc, dib

I have inherited an old-school MFC Windows CE program, and am having to make some modifications to it. As part of this I have to create a monochrome image with text on it, and both display it on a screen as well as send each row of the image to a printer one at a time.

I originally used a bitmap, and had success using DrawText() and getting a test string (Hello World) to display on the screen (this code is in Figure 1). However, I hit a wall at the stage where I am looking to extract the wrap data from the bitmap. What I am trying to get is an array with 1s or 0s representing black or white. I had first thought I would use GetBitmapBits() but unfortunately the code I am working with is so old that function is not supported yet. I thought I could get around this issue by using GetBitmap() and then accessing the bmBits parameter. However this appears to always be null which was confirmed when I found the following link: [Why does GetObject return an BITMAP with null bmBits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832292/why-does-getobject-return-an-bitmap-with-null-bmbits).

My next attempt was to follow the advice in the link and use CreateDIBSection() instead of CreateCompatibleBitmap(). This seems like the right path, and I should have access to the data I want, but unfortunately I cannot get the DIB to display (code is in Figure 2). I suspect I am doing something wrong in creating the header of the DIB, but I cannot figure out what my mistake is.

If anyone has suggestions for a way to access the data in the bitmap, or can see what I am doing wrong with the DIB, I would greatly appreciate the help!

*** FIGURE 1: Code to create and display a bitmap

```
void CRunPage::OnPaint() 
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);          // property page device context for painting
    CBitmap mBmp;               // CBitmap object for displaying built-in bitmaps
    CDC mDCMem;                 // CDC object to handle built-in bitmap
    int iWidth, iHeight;        // dimension to draw on the screen

    int icurLabel,              // current label index of open print file
        iLabelNum;              // number of labels in open print file
    LPBITMAPINFOHEADER pBMIH;   // bitmap header object for current label
    LPBYTE pImage;              // bitmap data for current label
    CSize size;                 // size of label
    int PreviewLeft,PreviewTop,PreviewWidth,PreviewHeight;
    CRect Rect;
    BITMAP bm;
    LPVOID bmBits=NULL;

    // Calculate the preview area
    PreviewLeft=5;
    PreviewTop=5;
    GetDlgItem(IDC_RUN_NEXT)->GetWindowRect(&Rect);
    ScreenToClient(&Rect);
    PreviewWidth=Rect.left-PreviewLeft*2;
    GetDlgItem(IDC_RUN_WRAPTEXT)->GetWindowRect(&Rect);
    ScreenToClient(&Rect);
    PreviewHeight=Rect.top-PreviewTop*2;

    CRect textRect;
    CString testText(_T("Hello World"));

    CBitmap * pOldBitmap;
    CBrush whiteBrush, *pOldBrush;
    CPen blackPen, *pOldPen;


    mDCMem.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);

    mBmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(&dc, PreviewWidth+PreviewLeft*2, PreviewHeight+PreviewTop*2);
    //mBmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(&dc, PreviewWidth, PreviewHeight);
    pOldBitmap = mDCMem.SelectObject(&mBmp);

    blackPen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    whiteBrush.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255));

    textRect.SetRect(0,0,PreviewWidth, PreviewHeight);

    // this means behind the text will be a white box w/ a black boarder
    pOldBrush = mDCMem.SelectObject(&whiteBrush);
    pOldPen = mDCMem.SelectObject(&blackPen);

    //these commands draw on the memory-only context (mDCMem)
    mDCMem.Rectangle(&textRect);
    mDCMem.DrawText((LPCTSTR)testText, 11, &textRect, DT_CENTER|DT_VCENTER);

    mDCMem.SelectObject(pOldBrush);
    mDCMem.SelectObject(pOldPen);

    dc.StretchBlt(PreviewLeft,PreviewTop, PreviewWidth, PreviewHeight, & mDCMem, 0, 0, PreviewWidth, PreviewHeight, SRCCOPY);

    mDCMem.SelectObject(pOldBitmap);

}
```

*** FIGURE 2: Trying to use a DIB instead of a bitmap

```
void CRunPage::OnPaint() 
{

    CPaintDC dc(this);          // property page device context for painting

    CBitmap mBmp;               // CBitmap object for displaying built-in bitmaps
    CDC mDCMem;                 // CDC object to handle built-in bitmap
    int iWidth, iHeight;        // dimension to draw on the screen

    int icurLabel,              // current label index of open print file
        iLabelNum;              // number of labels in open print file
    LPBITMAPINFOHEADER pBMIH;   // bitmap header object for current label
    LPBYTE pImage;              // bitmap data for current label
    CSize size;                 // size of label
    int PreviewLeft,PreviewTop,PreviewWidth,PreviewHeight;
    CRect Rect;
    BITMAP bm;

    // Calculate the preview area
    PreviewLeft=5;
    PreviewTop=5;
    GetDlgItem(IDC_RUN_NEXT)->GetWindowRect(&Rect);
    ScreenToClient(&Rect);
    PreviewWidth=Rect.left-PreviewLeft*2;
    GetDlgItem(IDC_RUN_WRAPTEXT)->GetWindowRect(&Rect);
    ScreenToClient(&Rect);
    PreviewHeight=Rect.top-PreviewTop*2;

    CRect textRect;
    CString testText(_T("Hello World"));

    CBitmap * pOldBitmap;
    CBrush whiteBrush, *pOldBrush;
    CPen blackPen, *pOldPen;

    LPBYTE pFWandImageMem=NULL, pImageMem=NULL, pTemp=NULL;
    int i=0,j=0, buffSize=0, numBytesPerRow=0, bitmapWidthPix,bitmapHeightPix;

    char *numBytesPerRowString;
    char temp;
    void ** ppvBits;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmif;
    BITMAPINFO bmi;
    HBITMAP myDIB, myOldDIB;

    mDCMem.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);

    //this rect is the area in which I can draw (its x,y location is set by BitBlt or StretchBlt
    //mBmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(&dc, PreviewWidth+PreviewLeft*2, PreviewHeight+PreviewTop*2);

    bmif.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmif.biWidth = PreviewWidth+PreviewLeft*2;
    bmif.biHeight = -(PreviewHeight+PreviewTop*2);//- means top down (I think? I tried both ways and neither worked)
    bmif.biPlanes = 1;
    bmif.biBitCount = 1;
    bmif.biCompression = BI_RGB; // no compression
    bmif.biSizeImage = 0; // Size (bytes) if image - this can be set to 0 for uncompressed images
    bmif.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bmif.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bmif.biClrUsed =0;
    bmif.biClrImportant = 0;

    bmi.bmiColors[0].rgbBlue=0;
    bmi.bmiColors[0].rgbGreen=0;
    bmi.bmiColors[0].rgbRed=0;
    bmi.bmiColors[0].rgbReserved=0;
    bmi.bmiColors[1].rgbBlue=255;
    bmi.bmiColors[1].rgbGreen=255;
    bmi.bmiColors[1].rgbRed=255;
    bmi.bmiColors[1].rgbReserved=0;

    bmi.bmiHeader=bmif;

    myDIB = CreateDIBSection(dc.GetSafeHdc(), &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, ppvBits, NULL, 0);

    myOldDIB = (HBITMAP)mDCMem.SelectObject(myDIB);//SelectObject(mDCMem, myDIB);
blackPen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, RGB(0, 0, 0));
whiteBrush.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255));

textRect.SetRect(0,0,PreviewWidth, PreviewHeight);

// this means behind the text will be a white box w/ a black boarder
pOldBrush = mDCMem.SelectObject(&whiteBrush);
pOldPen = mDCMem.SelectObject(&blackPen);

//these commands draw on the memory-only context (mDCMem)
mDCMem.Rectangle(&textRect);
mDCMem.DrawText((LPCTSTR)testText, 11, &textRect, DT_CENTER|DT_VCENTER);

mDCMem.SelectObject(pOldBrush);
mDCMem.SelectObject(pOldPen);

dc.StretchBlt(PreviewLeft,PreviewTop, PreviewWidth, PreviewHeight, & mDCMem, 0, 0, PreviewWidth, PreviewHeight, SRCCOPY);

mDCMem.SelectObject(myOldDIB);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So I made two minor changes to the DIB code, and it is displaying the image correctly now.

First, I changed the way I passed in my pointer to the CreateDIBSection():

```
void ** ppvBits;
```

to

```
LPBYTE pBits;
```

And then I had to change how I passed that into CreateDIBSection. I also explicitly casted the return of CreateDIBSection() to an HBITMAP:

```
myDIB = CreateDIBSection(dc.GetSafeHdc(), &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&pBits, NULL, 0);
```

to

```
myDIB = (HBITMAP) CreateDIBSection(dc.GetSafeHdc(), &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, ppvBits, NULL, 0);
```

I have not had a chance to see if I can access the image data, but I am past the initial issues now. Thanks to anyone who looked at this, and if people know how to do the first (device dependent bitmap) method I would be interested to know.